# WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 Api for session management

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Does WSO2 Identity Server has api for session management?

I have an app with SAML SSO.
What I would like to achieve is to check if for given saml token there is an active session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validity of the SAML token has nothing to do with validity of the user session.

In theory - when user does "logout", the identity server should execute SLO (single logout), however based on our experience with WSO2IS 5.0.0 it works only for limited number of options.

Since version 5.2.0 there's [OpenID Connect Session Management](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html) implemented using iframes, see http://malithiedirisinghe.blogspot.be/2016/03/openid-connect-session-management.html

But generally - you will have hard time to synchronize session between multiple service providers and WSO2 IS. With the claim based authentication (SAML, OAuth 2.0) the sessions between the IdP and SP are independent. (the only option I've see when the IdP is working as the pass-through-proxy for backend SP, but that's not what WSO2IS is intended for)

In version WSO2IS 5.3.0 there should be "user session management" implemented, but I haven't worked with that yet (managing session for WSO2IS, not external SPs)

Comment: Alrighty then, is there a way to tell WSO2 IS that I want to end the session (SLO) for a user, programatically?

Comment: @efreitora I'd guess using WSO2IS 5.3.0 user session management , as it should have web services for that (you may try to search between admin services https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM160/WSO2+Admin+Services ). I've never used the session management by myself. Is the SLO (SAML logout) not enough for you? Even sending a SLO request won't help, WSO2IS requires user's web session :/

Comment: @efreitora just a good advice - if you can, use the default SAML SLO. we spent a lot of time to come to a conclusion it's not worth the effort to force any other way to synchronize the sessions

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it does, you should investigate the documentation [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs) and [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/SCIM+APIs), those links were provided by a WSO2 team member to me or ask directly to your local  WSO2 office.

Comment: No it doens't. The SAML ticket provided has nothing to do with a user session.